# How to ignore empty dataseries in prometheus

Tags: max, prometheus, quantile

Calculating the maximum quantile over all dataseries is a problem for me:

**query**

```
http_response_time{job=~"^(x|y)$", quantile="0.95",...}
```

**result**

```
http_response_time{job="x",...} 0.26
http_response_time{job="y",...} NaN
```

This is how I would try to calculate the maximum:

```
avg(http_response_time{job=~"^(x|y)$",...})
```

Now the result will be "NaN". How can I ignore the "NaN" result (from the result section)?

**UPDATE 0**

The metric is a self made summary-metric.

**UPDATE 1**

Using prometheus version 1.8.

Comment: Can you share more information about the metric in question, and where it's coming from?

Comment: http_response_time{job="x",...} 0.26
http_response_time{job="y",...} NaN returned by http your node_exporter?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I didn't try this one with `NaN`, but you can simply filter by values with binary [operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/). Since `NaN` mathematically doesn't equal `NaN` you could try this trick (since a response time should be always positive):

```
avg(http_response_time{job=~"^(x|y)$",...} >= 0)
```

Comment: Good try. But "http_response_time{ quantile="0.95"} != NaN" does not filter/remove the "NaN" results.

Comment: Looks good. Will check it in detail before setting your answer as "correct". THX!

Comment: By definition, NaN boolean operations are strange.  For example "NaN != NaN" returns true in Javascript and pretty much every other language.